# How to test a react component that use "useQuery" outside ApolloProvider with the "client" set as an option

Tags: next.js, react-apollo

As I'm switching to an ssr app using next js following this "official" [post](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13/).

The main thing is that components using apollo aren't wrapper in an ApolloProvider. Instead the "client" is a singleton that can be used on the **client & server**.

Exemple:

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<
    { project: IProject },
    { id: number }
  >(GET_PROJECT, {
    variables: { id },
    client: getClient(), <==
  });
```

Everything works fine expect the tests who dosent. I think that it might be due to:

```
<MockedProvider mocks={[mockedProjectRequest]}>
```

MockedProvider doesn’t share the same client as the component... Thus, MockedProvider doesn’t accept a client as a parameter...

If anyone has found a work-around please share it :)

I've tried to pass the cache from the newly created client (in before each) like so:

```
const component = renderWithProvider(
        <MockedProvider addTypename={false} mocks={[mockedProjectRequest]} cache={client.cache}> <== here
          <Project />
        </MockedProvider>
      store,
      "/project/112551",
    );
```

But it dosent work, the mockedProjectRequest is just not readable by my test component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this new experimental library which might help with this use case:

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/frontend/using-apollo-client-with-next-js-13-releasing-an-official-library-to-support-the-app-router/

In order to make it easier to adopt Apollo Client in Next.js, the team is releasing an experimental library: @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support

This library will do all the right things for you whether you’re running under Server Components or if you’re running in Client Components.

Testing is also simplified as we can use a mockedProvider.